# SQL filtering by multiple columns

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a MySql table, which I want to query for rows in which **pairs** of columns are in a specific set.
For example, say my table looks like this:

```
id | f1  | f2
-------------    
1  | 'a' | 20
2  | 'b' | 20
3  | 'a' | 30
4  | 'b' | 20
5  | 'c' | 20
```

Now, I wish to extract rows in which the pair **(f1, f2)** are either ('a',30) or ('b', 20), namely rows 2,3,4. I also wish to do it using an 'IN' style filter, as I may have many pairs to fetch. If I try something like:

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE f1 IN ('a','b') AND f2 IN (30, 20)`

I get the Cartesian product of the values specified for f1 and f2 in the IN clauses, i.e. the rows with all possible combinations for f1 = 'a' or 'b', and f2 = 30, 20, hence row 1 is also selected.

In short, I'm need something like:

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (f1,f2) IN (('a',30), ('b',20))`

only with a valid SQL syntax :-)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That *is* valid syntax.

If you don't like it some other alternatives are:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE (f1, f2) = ('a', 30)
OR    (f1, f2) = ('b', 20)
```

Or using a join:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table T1
(
    SELECT 'a' AS f1, 30 AS f2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b', 20
) T2
ON T1.f1 = T2.f1 AND T1.f2 = T2.f2
```

Comment: LOL, I had the valid syntax all along. Validated in MySql. Thanks!

Comment: Let's raise the stakes: say I have an index on columns (f1, f2). Using the EXPLAIN phrase, I see that MySql uses the index for a single comparison (e.g. (f1,f2) = ('a',30)), but not for the 'IN' syntax. Any thoughts?

Comment: @bavaza: That sounds like an interesting question. I recommend you post it as a new question (not a comment) so that it can it be seen by more people.

Comment: @MarkByers is this viable in T-SQL? Or is there a similar way to do it in T-SQL?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (f1= 'a' AND f2=30) OR (f1='b' AND f2=20);
```

Comment: What if I want to have AND instead of OR.

Answer (score 0):

A rough but practical way is to use string concatenation:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE CONCAT(f1, '_', f2) IN ('a_30', 'b_20')
```

Comment: also potentially dangerous since 111 can mean {1, 11} or {11,1}

Comment: Right, I forgot the `_` in the `CONCAT`. Of course neither f1 or f2 should contain `_`!