# SQL filtering by multiple columns with indexes

Tags: sql, mysql

I'd like to expand [a question I posted a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488472/sql-filtering-by-multiple-columns):

I'm querying a table for rows in which pairs of columns are in a specific set. For example, consider the following table:

```
    id | f1  | f2
    -------------
    1  | 'a' | 20
    2  | 'b' | 20
    3  | 'a' | 30
    4  | 'b' | 20
    5  | 'c' | 20
```

And I wish to extract rows in which the pair **(f1, f2)** are in a specified set of pairs, e.g. (('a',30), ('b', 20),...). In the original question, [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61974/mark-byers) answered correctly that I can use the following syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (f1,f2) IN (('a',30), ('b',20))
```

This works fine, but I see some unexpected behavior regarding indexes:
I've defined a multi-column index for f1, f2, named *IndexF1F2*. Using the EXPLAIN phrase, I see that MySql uses the index for a single comparison, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (f1,f2) = ('a',30)
```

but not when using the 'IN' clause, as in the example above. Giving hints, e.g. `USE INDEX(IndexF1F2)` or even `FORCE INDEX(IndexF1F2)`, does not seem to make any difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [**known bug**](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46288) in `MySQL`.

Use this syntax:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    composite
WHERE   (f1, f2) = ('a', 30)
        OR (f1, f2) = ('b', 20)
```