# LINQ to Entity filter on multiple rows of other table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have Criteria table with columns `CriteriaID,CriteriaValueID,UserId,companyid`. Other table is `UserMaster` with fields as `UserID,UserName,Email`.
Now in Criteria table there are multiple rows for one user for multiple criteria. Here number of rows is dynamic. I am using LINQ to Entity. I need to search user using criteriavalueid and criteriaid using and expression.

```
E.g.
companyid UserID UserName 
1          1       ABC
1          2       BCD
2          3       CDE
CriteriaID CriteriaValueID UserId companyid
1           1               1       1
2           4               1       1
3           9               1       1
1           2               2       1
2           4               2       1
```

When i search lets say i want user with `CriteriaID =2` and `CriteriaValueID = 4` then LINQ to entity should return user ids 1,2.
Actually it can be multiple like 1. CriteriaID =2 and CriteriaValueID = 4 2. CriteriaID =3 and CriteriaValueID = 5. Here I have List of criteria for which we need users

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you even tried anything?

```
from c in Criteria
where c.CriteriaID = 2 && c.CriteriaValueID = 4
select c.User
```

This assumes you have foreign keys defined on database and navigation properties created in entity framework.

Comment: In above case i mentioned only one condition but actually it can be multiple like 
1. CriteriaID =2 and CriteriaValueID = 4 2. CriteriaID =3 and CriteriaValueID = 5. Here I have List of criteria for which we need users

Comment: In this case I don't know if it is possible in `EF`. You may need to fall back to stored procedure to do this. Here is helpful solution for `MySql` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488472/sql-filtering-by-multiple-columns, I think it should be possible to achieve something like this in `SQL Server` as well. And then mapping stored procedure to `EF` is pretty simple

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that you have your `Criteria` object and `CompanyUser` object, probably named something else.

In the example, I am adding the `Criteria` manually, but I assume you'll have something that adds the `Criteria` that you want and then similar for `Users`. It seems that the `CriteriaID` and `CriteriaValueID` are redundant, if you only compare the `UserID` and `CompanyID`, except for using `CriteriaID` as a unique identifier or primary key.

```
// Create a list of Criteria
List<Criteria> ListOfCriteria = new List<Criteria>();
// Add Criteria where Criteria ID = 2 and CriteriaValueID = 4 and Criteria ID = 2 
// Adding Criteria objects instead of retrieval for example, you want to retrieve the Criteria object from your existing list
ListOfCriteria.Add(new Criteria() { CriteriaID = 2, CriteriaValueID = 4, CompanyID = 1, UserID = 1 });
ListOfCriteria.Add(new Criteria() { CriteriaID = 1, CriteriaValueID = 1, CompanyID = 1, UserID = 1 });
// Create a list of your users
List<CompanyUser> ListOfUsers = new List<CompanyUser>();
// The below is to add users as shown in your example, ideally, you will be pulling your User object from database
ListOfUsers.Add(new CompanyUser() { CompanyID = 1, UserID = 1, UserName = "ABC" });
ListOfUsers.Add(new CompanyUser() { CompanyID = 1, UserID = 2, UserName = "BCD" });
ListOfUsers.Add(new CompanyUser() { CompanyID = 2, UserID = 3, UserName = "CDE" });
// Retrieve a single user that matches all your requirements
CompanyUser RetrievedUser = ListOfUsers.Where(a => ListOfCriteria.All(b => b.UserID == a.UserID && b.CompanyID == a.CompanyID)).FirstOrDefault();

if(RetrievedUser == null)
    MessageBox.Show("No user found");
else
    MessageBox.Show(RetrievedUser.UserName);
```